Trying to Export Attachmnets from Freshservice
I'm trying to export all of our attachments from fresh service -
I can get the to ticket from the API using 'https://domain.freshservice.com/api/v2/tickets/20'
and i can click on the attachment url link it works but I'd have to do this manually for over 10k tickets we want to download them and store them locally.
I tried using the  'https://domain.freshservice.com/api/v2/attachments/1'
But i get a 400 error .
has anyone had a similar experience or can please help me in getting these attachments exported.
Trying to export all attachments from freshservice to store them locally.
